# __assume() seems to cause an internal error in NVCC: "Call has wrong number of parameters..."

Tags: visual-c++, optimization, cuda, intrinsics, nvcc

I have the following code which causes an error in the context of a larger codebase:

```
struct Quadruple
{
    double _sum;
    double _corr;

    // Fast multiply by -1, 0 or +1 (doesn't need extended precision operations).
    __device__ inline Quadruple& MulSign(const int8_t sign);
};

// ...

__device__ inline Quadruple& Quadruple::MulSign(const int8_t sign)
{
    __assume(-1 <= sign && sign <= 1); // enable more optimization premises
    _sum *= sign;
    _corr *= sign;
    return *this;
}

// ...

int8_t y = /* ... read from memory ... */;
Quadruple a = /* ... computed here ... */;
Quadruple b = Quadruple(a).MulSign(y);
```

When compiling the code with CUDA 8RC + MSVC++2013 I get the following error:

```
1>  Compiling CUDA source file Example.gpu.cu...
1>  
1>  D:\ExDir>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_21,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -D_DENSE_REP -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W4 /nologo /Ox /Zi  /MD " -o x64\Release\Example.gpu.cu.obj "D:\ExDir\Example.gpu.cu" 
1>ptxas C : /Users/ExUser/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00002ffc_00000000-4_CuSvm.gpu.ptx, line 2513; error : Call has wrong number of parameters
1>  ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
1>  Example.gpu.cu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 8.0.targets(599,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_21,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -D_DENSE_REP -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W4 /nologo /Ox /Zi  /MD " -o x64\Release\Example.gpu.cu.obj "D:\ExDir\Example.gpu.cu"" exited with code 255.
```

After commenting out `__assume(-1 <= sign && sign <= 1);`, the code compiles ok.

Is it a bug in NVCC, or is MSVC++'s `__assume` just not supported by NVCC, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround (keeping `__assume` or an equivalent, of course)?

Answer (score 4):

`__assume()` is a [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw.aspx) (and subsequently Intel icc) compiler intrinsic. It isn't part of the C++ language and it isn't supported in CUDA (or in GCC or Clang for that matter).